# Why does the asp.net head control mangle link elements?

Tags: asp.net, controls

Suppose I have the following markup in a standard ASP.NET 2.0 web form:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Snazzy Page</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="<%= PathUtilities.AssetPath %>/css/page.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=PathUtilities.AssetPath %>/lib/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

What's odd is that this renders the `<link>` element literally, with the embedded code brackets, while it interpolates the output of the same code into the script tag.  In other words, the browser sees this:

```
<head><title>My Snazzy Page

</title><link type="text/css" href="&lt;%= PathUtilities.AssetPath %>/css/page.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/rmt/lib/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Obviously the problem disappears if I remove the `runat="server"` from the head element.

Answer (score 2):

Well what you're doing is (no offence) a bit silly, that is - having a `<head>` **server-side** element, with a nested `<link>` **client-side** element with **server-side** href attribute

You are dynamically rendering the **href** value from server code anyway, so a better solution would be to dynamically render the link tag from the server altogether.

Example (code-behind of page)

```
// Define an HtmlLink control.
HtmlLink myHtmlLink = new HtmlLink();
myHtmlLink.Href = "/css/page.css";
myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");

// Add the HtmlLink to the Head section of the page.
Page.Header.Controls.Add(myHtmlLink);
```

Your ASPX then becomes much neater:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Snazzy Page</title>
    <!-- CSS/JS included dynamically -->
</head>
```

Comment: I agree it's odd and there is more than one reasonable alternative.  I'm wondering if there's some underlying principle at play with interpolation of markup in built-in controls like head.

Comment: So im getting the impression you're not so much looking for a solution, but an explanation.